# Get month wise records of payments for last six months

Tags: sql-server, join, common-table-expression

Table Structure:

1. Invoice

[image: Invoice]

2. Invoice Payment

[image: Invoice Payment]

Current Query:

```
;WITH cte (clientid, invoiceid,  paid, disc)
As
(
    Select client_id clientId, vinvoice_Id invoiceId,  sum(amount_received) paid, sum(discount) disc
    From tbl_Vendor_Invoice_Payment
    Group by vinvoice_id, client_id
)
Select I.date, I.total_price, Isnull(paid, 0) Paid, (Total_price - Isnull(paid,0) - Isnull(disc,0)) Balance
From tbl_Vendor_invoice I Left join cte On I.client_id = cte.clientId 
And I.vinvoice_id = cte.invoiceid
order by vinvoice_id desc
```

Output:

[image: Result]

But my requirement is to get month-wise result of last six months as below:

```
Month       total_price  Paid     Balance
--------------------------------------------
October     800.00       750.00   50.00
September   200.00       100.00   100.00
August      350.00       350.00   0.00
.........
```

Can anyone please help me to get this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,[vi.date]),0), SUM(vi.total_price) total_price, SUM(vip.amount_received) Paid, SUM(vip.balance) balance
FROM tbl_Vendor_Invoice vi
INNER JOIN tbl_Vendor_Invoice_Payment vip
    on vi.vInvoice_Id = vip.vInvoice_Id
WHERE [vi.date] >= DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,[vi.date]),0))
GROUP BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,[vi.date]),0)
```

This will group by the first day of the month, including the year.  If you want just the month name, you can extract that using `DATENAME(month, [date])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer:

```
;WITH cte (clientid, invoiceid,  paid, disc)
As
(
    Select client_id clientId, vinvoice_Id invoiceId,  sum(amount_received) paid, sum(discount) disc
    From tbl_Vendor_Invoice_Payment
    Group by vinvoice_id, client_id
)
SELECT DATENAME(month, [date]) mMonth, SUM(Isnull(paid, 0)) Amount_Paid
FROM tbl_Vendor_Invoice vi
INNER JOIN cte vip on vi.vinvoice_Id = vip.invoiceid
WHERE [date] >= DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,getdate()),0))
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, [date]), MONTH([date])
ORDER BY MONTH([date])
```